# How to define field value of an annotation from property file

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm playing with spring and activemq and use the following method to receive messages from message broker:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "sample.queue")
public void receiveQueue(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

I just thought it would be nice to be able to configure `destination` from my `application.properties`. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the way. Suppose `message-consumer.destination` property from `application.properties` defines the desired destination, then it would be as simple as this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${message-consumer.destination}")
public void receiveQueue(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

**Below are my old thoughts on how to externalize queue destination:**

Here is the message consumer.

```
@Component
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

    }
}
```

Here is the jms configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfiguration implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    @Value("${message-consumer.destination}")
    private String destination;

    @Inject
    private MessageListener messageListener;

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
        endpoint.setId("audit.logging");
        endpoint.setDestination(destination);
        endpoint.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a variable to this but even if you can I think a better solution is to use a [DestinationResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/destination/DestinationResolver.html) as this is what the [destination](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#destination--) is used for.

There is some explanation of this in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-destinations).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by reading the properties file at class level:

Create a file 'my.properties' in your resources dir:

```
destination = sample.queue
```

And a wrapper class:

```
public class MyProperties {

    private static final RespourceBundle BUNDLE = RespourceBundle.getBundle("/my.properties");

    public static String destination() {
        return BUNDLE.getProperty("destination");
    }
}
```

Then change your code like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = MyProperties.destination())
public void receiveQueue(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Haven't tested it, but I think that should work.

EDIT: I'm sure I've used constants in annotations before. Maybe this static method is causing the problem. Try this:

```
public class MyProperties {

    private static final RespourceBundle BUNDLE = RespourceBundle.getBundle("/my.properties");

    public static final String DESTINATION = BUNDLE.getProperty("destination");

}
```

and:

```
@JmsListener(destination = MyProperties.DESTINATION)
public void receiveQueue(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

EDIT: one last attempt

```
public class MyProperties {

    private static final RespourceBundle BUNDLE = RespourceBundle.getBundle("/my.properties");

    public static final String DESTINATION;

    static {
        DESTINATION = BUNDLE.getProperty("destination");
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Compiler fails with: `element value must be a constant expression`. The thing is that `private static final ResourceBundle =  RespourceBundle.getBundle("/my.properties");` is not a constant, because it is not a primitive or a predeclared value

Comment: The same thing is here `public static final String DESTINATION = BUNDLE.getProperty("destination");` is not a constant. I've tried to make destination as `private final String` in the same class and initialize it through constructor injection using `@Value`, but also without success.

Comment: DESTINATION certainly is a constant! It is intialized when the class is loaded and can never be changed after that. One last attempt above.

Comment: The problem is that DESTINATION is not a [compile time constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), that's why even in this case compiler will throw: `The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression`

Comment: Aha. You mean it's not an inlinable value. That's true, so then this won't work at all.

Comment: For instance, `DESTINATION` field defined in this way: `public static final String DESTINATION="destination";` will not cause any problems in annotation, but certainly this option is not acceptable in my case.